# How to remove 'URL' prefixed before the URL in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, urls, custom-bib

I had to create my own bibliography style to format my .bib database using custom-bib and an external language file.

I have a couple of problems left, one is that when I have an entry with a URL, the style inserts the text 'URL' before the URL so it looks like e.g.:

> URL https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask.

Is there an easy way to edit the .bst file to remove the prefix 'URL'?

The .bst file has the following function:

```
FUNCTION {write.url}

{

  url

  duplicate$ empty$

   { pop$ }

   { "\newline\urlprefix\url{" swap$ * "}" * write$ newline$ 

}
```

I'm using LyX and I'm not a programmer so if it gets too hairy it's probably not worth it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there an easy way to edit the `.bst` file to remove the prefix 'URL'?

Good news: You needn't edit your bespoke bibliography style file. It suffices to issue the instruction

```
\def\urlprefix{}
```

somewhere in the preamble. After making this change, be sure to re-run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate the change.

---

If you wanted to edit the bst file, you could proceed as follows: Open the bst file in an editor and locate the function `format.url`. It should look like this:

```
FUNCTION {format.url}
{ url empty$
    { "" }
    { "\urlprefix\url{" url * "}" * }
  if$
}
```

Delete the substring `\urlprefix`. Then, save the bst file and rerun BibTeX and LaTeX. If, instead, the `makebst` utility created a function called `write.url`, simply delete the substring `\urlprefix` from that function.

Comment: Great you saved me much time, adding \def\urlprefix{} in the preamble was enough I didn't have to do anything else.