# Biblatex: Prevent URL:-prefix

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

When using the `@online` bibliography entry in biblatex the actual URL always gets prefixed with `URL:` (for an image see the first link below). I'd like to know how I can remove that prefix.

While searching on the web for this I stumble upon [Delete "URL:" prefix in biblatex online entries? include date visited?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336317/delete-url-prefix-in-biblatex-online-entries-include-date-visited) and [How to remove 'URL' prefixed before the URL in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395234/how-to-remove-url-prefixed-before-the-url-in-bibliography).

<strike>The answer to the first example doesn't really care about answering how to get rid of the `URL:` prefix</strike> (EDIT: Actually it does but the solution is quite hidden in the rest of what gets done there) and the solution in the second link (using `\def\urlprefix{}`) doesn't work.

Does somebody know how I can turn that prefix off? So what I want is something like this:

```
[1] 12. Oct. 2018. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask
```

And here's an example-entry:

```
@online{Galleries,
    date = {2018-10-28},
    url = {http://www.galleries.com/Scheelite}
}
```

PS: I'm not sure how important this is but I am using `latexmk` with the `-lualatex` option (so lualatex will be used to compile the document) and `biber` as the backend for `biblatex`.

Comment: Untested: `\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}`. However, probably the proper way to deal with it is to redefine the localized string, for which a MEWB would be required to reduce the guesswork.

Comment: Mhhh, upon reading the first linked question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/336317/35864) the answer there does exactly the right thing (amongst others, so it might be a bit harder to figure out which bit of code takes care of what result): `\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}` and definitely gets rid of the "URL:". If it does not work for you, please show us a short example document of what you have tried (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)

Comment: @moewe Indeed... Didn't find that little line in all the other stuff that was going on in that answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to adjust your question to point out that the answer in fact does provide an adequate answer. I was a bit uncomfortable with the claim that the answer does not care to address the problem (I'm not a native speaker, so my connotations when I read that line might have been too strong, but I felt that it was unfair on the answer). The question and answer serve as a good example why it makes sense to only ask one specific thing per question and not several things (however closely they are related).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can adjust the field format for the `url` field. The default is

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
```

So you could try

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}

\begin{document}
\cite{markey,ctan}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: CTAN (2006). CTAN. The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network. http://www.ctan.org (visited on 01/10/2006).//Markey, Nicolas (16th Oct. 2005). Tame the BeaST. The B to X of BibTeX. Version 1.3. http://mirror.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf (visited on 01/10/2006).]

Comment: Add `\urlstyle{sf}` to change the font from courier to something more attractive (and tighter).