# How to make `url` and `urldate` be the last entries of bibliography entries

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

**I have this entry in my bibliography:**

```
@online{DBHammerMRScrewdriver,
    author = {Mark C. Chu-Carroll},
    title = {Databases are hammers; MapReduce is a screwdriver.},
    year = {2008},
    url = {https://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2008/01/22/databases-are-hammers-mapreduc},
    urldate = {2019-01-07},
    note = {website},
}
```

**This produces the following result.**

[image]

**Is the following possible?**

- url attribute always starts at a new line.
- the word "url" is omitted in the pdf. (Edit: The answer to this question can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/457869/5440) as @Ulrike pointed out in the comments (adding `\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}`).

My minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{Thesis}  % Use the "Thesis" style, based on the ECS Thesis style by Steve Gunn
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{DBHammerMRScrewdriver}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

(Is this sufficient? The overleaf.com project I use also lists some other human-readable files: `3dplot.sty`, `lstpatch.sty`, `Thesis.cls`, `tikz-er2.sty`, `vector.sty`. If you need the content of these files, let me know and I will provide them.)

Comment: Show a complete example, that we can compile. The answer depends on your bibliography style.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, is this sufficient or should I add some of the other files, too? They are very complicated and hard to reduce to a MWE and I don't want to clutter this question.

Comment: Exchange the thesis class with e.g. book, it is probably not relevant. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/457869/2388 for the prefix.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thanks! The linked answer helped me to omit the word `URL:`. Changing the `documentclass` from `Thesis` to `book` however had no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example a quick hack is to add `\newline` in your used `\DeclareFieldFormat`:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\newline\url{#1}}
```

With the following MWE (please see I used class `article` to get text and bibliography on one page)

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{DBHammerMRScrewdriver,
    author = {Mark C. Chu-Carroll},
    title = {Databases are hammers; MapReduce is a screwdriver.},
    year = {2008},
    url = {https://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2008/01/22/databases-are-hammers-mapreduc},
    urldate = {2019-01-07},
    note = {website},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{article}  % Use the "Thesis" style, based on the ECS Thesis style by Steve Gunn
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\newline\url{#1}} % <==========================


\begin{document}
\cite{DBHammerMRScrewdriver}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image]